# How to shuffle a number following a sequence (not random)

Tags: javascript, function, math

I need to build a function that returns a given number shuffled writing one digit from the front of the number and the following taken from the back, then the 3rd digit from the front of the number and the 4th from the back and so on.

Example:

const initialNumber = 123456 should return 
const finalNumber = 162534

or

const initialNumber2 = 104 should return 
const finalNumber2 = 140

Also, the number should be between the values of 0 and 100.000.000.

How to do it? Should I first transform the number into an array first of all using the split() method and then using a for loop?

Comment: Sounds like you're pretty close :) Keep on trying

Comment: I am working on a demo for you. Yes you will either have to split your number to an array to comfortable handle it or you'll need to think of a recursive logic which will work on the number places without using the array splitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer converting the number to a string, then using that string in a for loop.

```js
function shuffle(num) {
  var str = num.toString();
  var result = "";
  if(!isNaN(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 100000000) {
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
        result += str[Math.floor(i / 2)];
      } else {
        result += str[str.length - Math.floor(i / 2 + 1)];
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(shuffle(123456));  // 162534
console.log(shuffle(1234567)); // 1726354
console.log(shuffle(104));     // 140
```

Comment: Hi For Java what could be the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Java developer. You can open a new thread asking for a Java solution.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why `i / 2` for the index, can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with splitting the input into array and `reduce`:

```js
const shuffle = input => input.toString().split('').reduce((acc, item, index, data) => {
  const arr = (index % 2 ? data.slice().reverse() : data);
  return acc.concat(arr[Math.floor(index / 2)]);
}, []).join('');

console.log(shuffle(104));     // 140
console.log(shuffle(123456));  // 162534
console.log(shuffle(1234567)); // 1726354
```

A bit reduced code:

```
const shuffle = input => input.toString().split('').reduce((acc, item, index, data) =>
  acc.concat((index % 2 ? data.slice().reverse() : data)[Math.floor(index / 2)]), []
).join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

This may work as a very basic algo.

```
function shuffleNum(num,i){ 
    var numArr = num.toString().split(''); 
    var front = numArr.splice(0,i); 
    var back = numArr.pop(); 
    var shuffledArr = front.concat(back,numArr); 
    return parseFloat(shuffledArr.join('')); 
}
// Test
var num = 12345; 
for(var i=0;i<num.toString().length;i++){ 
    num = shuffleNum(num); 
    console.log(num); 
}
// Output
// 51234
// 45123
// 34512
// 23451
// 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use array push function.

```
function shuffle(a) {
      var b = a.toString();
      var c = [];
      for(let i=0; i<b.length/2; i++) {
        c.push(b[i]);
        if(i==(Math.ceil(b.length/2)-1) && b.length%2==1) continue;
        c.push(b[b.length-i-1]);
      }
      return c.join("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code snippet.

```
public static int solution(int a) {
    int[] arr = Integer.toString(a).chars().map(e->e-'0').toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
        int j=1;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                temp[i] = arr[i/2];
            } else {
                temp[i] = arr[arr.length - j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```